# Javascript, pass value from vbscript scripted-javascript to a function in javascript file?

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

Apologies for the confusion,

I have two files, one vbscript/asp(classic) and the other a javascript file.

Ive created some google API tables in the vbscript and because of this i scripted the javascript functions in the vbscript file ie:

```
response.write "function DrawGoogleGraph(){" & vbcrlf
```

etc

everything is working, but i want to now use a value i collect in the vbscript-scripted-javascript function to pass into a function which is in my .js file. It doesnt seem to allow this.

I have surrounded the vbscript-scripted javascript with the  tags so i guess it is out of scope?

How can i get around this? I cant really move the Google stuff into my Javascript function and my Ajax calls are all set up in my .js files.

Answer (score 0):

Output a script block in your page that sets the variables for your .js file:

```
%>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var something = <%=vbSomething%>
</script>
<%
```